# Fill the inside of a pie donut chart d3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

[image: Example]
I am trying to create the image above using d3

http://jsfiddle.net/Spwizard/LBzx7/1/

```
var dataset = {
hddrives: [20301672, 9408258, 2147483, 21474836, 35622,32210000],
};

var width = 460,
height = 300,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#2DA7E2"]);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(radius - 100)
.outerRadius(radius - 70);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
.data(pie(dataset.hddrives))
  .enter().append("path")
 .attr("class", "arc")
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
.attr("d", arc);
svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("class", "inside")
  .text(function(d) { return '56%'; });
svg.append("text")
   .attr("dy", "2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("class", "data")
  .text(function(d) { return 'some text'; });
```

Im struggling to see how to deal with the background color of the inner circle and dealing with the space left for storage

Thanks

Comment: For the former you would append a separate `circle` and fill it accordingly. For the latter, you would need a dummy element that represents free space that you know not to draw.

Comment: Thanks I've updated the fiddle to sort the background out, just not sure how to do deal with free space

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LBzx7/2/) where you set the opacity based on an attribute.

Comment: Excellent thanks for your help
http://jsfiddle.net/Spwizard/LBzx7/4/

Comment: Great, I'll post that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

To get a "background", you can add another circle with the respective fill colour. To deal with the free space, you can selectively set the opacity of one of the segments to 0. In your example, I've done that for the last slice:

```
.style("opacity", function(d, i) { return i == dataset.hddrives.length - 1 ? 0 : 1; })
```

Complete example (provided by OP) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Spwizard/LBzx7/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Just append text:

```html
svg.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr('font-size', '20px')
  .attr('y', '5')
  .text(dataset.hddrives + "%");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).